# No massflow to doubleacting cylinder

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to make a double acting cylinder in Modelica. The model is based on the Modelica.Fluid package (4.0.0).

To test the cylinder model I have made a regenerative hydraulic circuit.

The test setup runs, however, when I look at the mass flow to port_a it is zero (expected to be mass flow from MassFlowSource_T + the mass flow from port_b [see snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Doc.png)). The force is zero as Aa=Ab.

I cannot find the error...so hope someone can help me out.

My .mo code for the double acting cylinder and test setup is given below.

```
model DoubleActingCylinder 
  // Import
  import Modelica.Constants.small;
  // Medium
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium "Medium in the     component";
  // Connectors
  extends
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialElementaryOneFlangeAndSupport2
    (s(start=small));
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_a port_a(redeclare package Medium = Medium) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-60, -100}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {60, -98}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_b port_b(redeclare package Medium = Medium) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {60, -100}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-60, -100}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  // Constants
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Area Aa "Area chamber a";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Area Ab "Area chamber b";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length L "Cylinder length";
  parameter Medium.Density rho_nominal = Medium.density_pTX(Medium.p_default, Medium.T_default, Medium.X_default) "Density";
equation
  // Mass flow rate to chamber a and block
  port_a.m_flow = der(Aa*s*rho_nominal);
  port_b.m_flow = der(Ab*(L-s)*rho_nominal);
  // Cylinder force
  -flange.f = port_a.p*Aa-port_b.p*Ab;
  // Enthalpy port_a
  port_a.h_outflow=Medium.specificEnthalpy_pTX(Medium.p_default, Medium.T_default, Medium.X_default) ;
  port_b.h_outflow=Medium.specificEnthalpy_pTX(Medium.p_default, Medium.T_default, Medium.X_default) ;
annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end DoubleActingCylinder;

model TestCylinderModel
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;
  DoubleActingCylinder doubleActingCylinder(replaceable package Medium = Medium, Aa = 0.01, Ab = 0.01, L = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-6, -6}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass mass(m = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {26, -6}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary( replaceable package Medium = Medium,m_flow = 1, nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-50, -46}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1(nPorts = 1, p = 1e5, replaceable package Medium = Medium)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-52, -12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.SpringDamper springDamper(c = 100, d = 15)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {54, -6}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Fixed fixed annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {76, -40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(doubleActingCylinder.flange, mass.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{4, -6}, {16, -6}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  connect(boundary1.ports[1], doubleActingCylinder.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-42, -12}, {-28, -12}, {-28, -30}, {-12, -30}, {-12, -16}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(doubleActingCylinder.port_b, doubleActingCylinder.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-12, -16}, {-22, -16}, {-22, -24}, {-14, -24}, {-14, -22}, {-10, -22}, {-10, -24}, {0, -24}, {0, -16}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(boundary.ports[1], doubleActingCylinder.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-40, -46}, {4, -46}, {4, -16}, {0, -16}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(fixed.flange, springDamper.flange_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{76, -40}, {76, -6}, {64, -6}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  connect(mass.flange_b, springDamper.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{36, -6}, {44, -6}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end TestCylinderModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You connected `port_a` with `port_b` of `doubleActingCylinder`. This results in a direct connection of `boundary` and `boundary1`, so the medium simply takes this path.

[image: highlighted connection]

Remove the connection and you will get the expected mass flow in `doubleActingCylinder`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The reason I chose to connect port_a and port_b is to make a regenerative circuit where the flow from port_b is going back to port_a. My issue is that this doesn't happen for testsystem/cylinder I have made. Do you know how I can get that?